# Share the same comments between more pages

Tags: taxonomy, comments

Scenario: I need to share the same comments between more pages.
Instead of simply using the post ID to load comments, I want to use a combination of two taxonomies' id.
For instance:

- Taxonomy 1: tag
- Taxonomy 2: place

So for all the posts with the same tag and place I want to show the same comments.
Is there any way to achieve this in wordpress?

Comment: I guess you need a hidden custom post type and a post for each combination, because WP comments depend on a post ID.

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom type of comments with some metadata based on the existing comment system?

Comment: I think that the combination of WP_Comment_Query and add_comment_meta could lead to a possible solution to my problem. Any feedback from someone more experienced than me?